# What is the best way to replace content in an HTML email template in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, aot

I have an HTML email template stored in `assets/templates/commands-report.html`

This template file has `*ngIF`, `*ngFor` `[ngStyle]` etc.

In my service I have written the following function which takes the template file content which I get by an HTTP call. This works perfectly in dev mode. Which means, all my data in the HTML email template gets rendered and I am able to send the HTML as a API payload.
 However when I do a production build with `ng build --prod`, and try to navigate to the code, I get an error `Runtime compiler is not loaded`

```
public enrichHTMLEmailTemplate(template: string, vc: ViewContainerRef, data: any): Observable<any> {

let templateSubject = new Subject<any>();

const tmpCmp = Component({ template })(class {

  ngOnInit() {
  }
});

const tmpModule = NgModule({
  declarations: [tmpCmp],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})(class { });

let cmpRef: ComponentRef<any>;
this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
  .then((factories) => {
    const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
    cmpRef = f.create(this.injector, [], null, this.moduleRef);
    cmpRef.instance.name = 'email-component';
    cmpRef.instance.data = data;
    vc.insert(cmpRef.hostView, 1);

    setTimeout(() => {

      templateSubject.next(cmpRef.location.nativeElement.innerHTML);
    }, 3000);
  });

return templateSubject.asObservable();
}
```

I am using angular v5.2.0

Let me know what will be the good way to enrich the HTML data from angular side. Also point me to any npm package if exists to do the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could probably simply use a component which has that template, but hide it using CSS, get a reference to that component's element, and use innerHTML to get its rendered HTML code. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kbuff5?file=src%2Fapp%2Femail.component.ts

Comment: You could also achieve something similar using [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)